# GetReferenceNearestTargetFramwork task failed unexpectedly. Invalid framework V4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I'm am trying to build a VS2010 project in VS2019. I also get this error message in  VS2017 as well.

The project will not build because it seems to not recognize MSbuild 4.0 as being valid.

This is the error:

```
  The "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" task failed unexpectedly.
    System.ArgumentException: Invalid framework version 'V4.0'.
    at NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework.ParseFrameworkName(String frameworkName, IFrameworkNameProvider mappings)
    at NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework.Parse(String folderName, IFrameworkNameProvider mappings)
 at
```

NuGet.Build.Tasks.GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask.TryParseFramework(String framework, String errorMessage, MSBuildLogger logger, NuGetFramework& nugetFramework)

Here is the task that fails:

```
 <GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask AnnotatedProjectReferences="@(_ProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkPossibilities)"
                                            CurrentProjectTargetFramework="$(ReferringTargetFrameworkForProjectReferences)"
                                            CurrentProjectName="$(MSBuildProjectName)"
                                            FallbackTargetFrameworks="$(AssetTargetFallback)"
                                            Condition="'@(_ProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkPossibilities->Count())' != '0' and '$(ReferringTargetFrameworkForProjectReferences)' != ''">
      <Output ItemName="AnnotatedProjects" TaskParameter="AssignedProjects" />
    </GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask>
```

Comment: Edit the project file of the project whose build failed, change the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` property from `V4.0 to v4.0` can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask` will be called during build process.

And see                                             `Condition="'@(_ProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkPossibilities->Count())' != '0' and '$(ReferringTargetFrameworkForProjectReferences)' != ''"`, this task will run when current project have `project reference` to other projects.

If this task executes, the value of `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` will be passed to `GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask` class from `NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll`. And it can't recognize the `V4.0`, in VS2019, the framewrok version starts with `v` instead of `V`.

So the **workaround** is to open the xx.csproj file, and change the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>V4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` to `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` and run a rebuild. Hope it helps:)